# Time complexity of linked list traversal in two passes

Tags: algorithm, linked-list

I know that traversing a linked list from head to tail takes O(n) time. What if we traverse it twice? Is it still O(n), correct? Because I'm basically O(n + n) = O(2n) ~ O(n).

Comment: well.. yes. by definition `0 < f(n) < cg(n)` => `0 < 2n < cn` hence: `c > 2` for each positive `n` so yes, `f(2n) ∈ O(n)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Indeed you can say if `f(n)` is in `O(n)`, `f(2n)` is in `O(n) too. It comes from the definition of the symbol.

By definition there is a constant `c > 0` and `N0` such that `f(n) < c * n` for all `n > N0`. Hence, `f(2n) < c' * n` for `n >‌ N0 / 2` and constant `c'`. Therefore, `f(2n)` is in `O(n)` too.

Notice that the statement "if `f(n)` is in `O(g(n))`, also `f(2n)` is in `O(g(n))`" is not correct at all! The contradiction example is when `f(n) = g(n) = 2^n`.